# Textview is not truncating the text

Tags: android, textview

Following is my .xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    ...
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAlternateRoad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fancy_dashboard_max_speed_circle_strock_size"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="Via A11"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textColor="#808080"
        android:textSize="@dimen/fancy_dashboard_lable_size" />

</TableRow>
```

I am calling the above .xml file in my main view .xml as following,

```
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.85"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layAlternateRoute"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fancy_dashboard_max_speed_circle_strock_size"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_round_rect_alternate_route" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0KRs.png

I am displaying a view on the screen which has above TableRow element. I am setting this Textview `tvAlternateRoad`'s text value at run time. Sometimes when Text is large then it is moving outside the view. I tried to truncate it using `android:ellipsize="end"` from some S.O. posts but it seems it is not working now a days.

Can somebody help me on this?

Comment: Can check adding android:singleLine="true" this code

Comment: Thanks but I have tried that too,

Comment: I have tried it too and it's working for me. I followed tutorial from here http://myandroidtuts.blogspot.com/2013/07/ellipsize-property-of-android.html

Comment: @sur007, I have already tried it but result is same :(

Comment: you can set padding for that text view.

Comment: @Rajsundar, Thanks, I tried it, but nothing happened...:(

Comment: try this once android:ellipsize="marquee" and can you remove android:lines="1"

Comment: @sur007, If I remove it then it will wrap the text to next lines. I have already tried ellipsize="marquee"

Comment: you can reduce the text view size

Comment: can you please post your code in detail?

Comment: @Rajsundar, How can I do it ?

Comment: what about spannable textview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after long effort I have solve the issue my self.

Logic:

- fetch the screen size programmatically
- int screen_width = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
- then I used 42% of the screen_width as maxwidth of textView
- ((TextView)alternate.findViewById(R.id.tvAlternateRoad)).setMaxWidth((int)(screen_width*0.42));
- I have also set below values in xml
- android:ellipsize="marquee"
- android:maxLines="1"

Answer (score 1):

Give paddingRight to text view. Also, text view has width wrap content and no relation with any other view. So your text view width can exceed the rounded corner background image as per text length. So either give some maxWidth value or relate it to some other views.

**Edit**

I just made this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
       android:id="@+id/textview_Statu"
            style="@style/text_view_login_style"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/more_txt3_margin_t"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"
            android:textColor="@color/blue_end" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

In graphical view, It looks like this
[image: graphical view of text view]

Its working fine.

Comment: How can I relate my textview to some other view ?

Comment: alignRight with some view if it is wrapped in relativelayout.

Comment: Also, try by giving fixed width.

Comment: Hi Seema, any other solution please ?

Comment: as per xml code posted, I cant see where background (rounded corner black) is given. Can you post complete xml

Comment: background (round corner black) is given in another .xml file, and I am fetching this (textview xml) into that .xml along with round corner black .xml, got it or should I explain in gujarati ?

Comment: check my edited code. And its better to explain by help of code and screenshots rather than Gujarati.

Comment: Thanks, but what you suggested is working fine when I test in HelloWorld(new app) but this is not working in my all :(

Comment: This implies there is some conflict in properties of view setting background and text view being used to set text. Resulting in unexpected output. So crosscheck both views.

Comment: Hi Seema, finally I have solved issue my self, You can check my answer :), thanks for all the effort you spent on my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that `TextView` will do different things with respect to wrapping and truncating depending on the container it's in.  Try having the `TableRow` cell be, for instance, a `FrameLayout`.  Then put your `TextView` inside the `FrameLayout` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

try this

tablelayout should be

```
<TableLayout
 android:id="@+id/tbl"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
  >
```

the remaining part should be

```
 <TableRow 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"

      >

 <TextView


        android:id="@+id/tvAlternateRoad"


     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:minLines="1"

                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fancy_dashboard_max_speed_circle_strock_size"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:text="Via A11"
               android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#808080"
                android:textSize="@dimen/fancy_dashboard_lable_size" />
```

Comment: @user4583559 can you please post your new xml?and a screenshot on what you get ?

Comment: I have added three lines `android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
android:minLines="1"` replaced with my `android:lines="1"` and output is same

Comment: set android:layout_width="wrap_content"? can you post a screenshot?

Comment: make it match_parent please

Comment: Tried that too but no result at all :(

Comment: set android:layout_width="match_parent" for tablerow also

Comment: Tried, but same result again :(

Comment: include android:layout_weight="1" this works  i tried in my xml

Comment: @user4583559 tried include android:layout_weight="1" it's working for me i tried it myself

Comment: @user4583559 you are again repeating the mistake you should set the width of tablelayout,tablerow and textview as match parent

Comment: Hi Karthika, finally I have solved issue my self, You can check my answer :), thanks for all the effort you spent on my question.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:
android:singleLine="true" and android:ellipsize="end"
and set a fixed width for your textview like "match_parent" or something in dp like "180dp" etc.
singleLine="true" needs your textview to have a fixed width which is not provided by "wrap_content".
A textview will only show ellipses at the end of its view's bounds and since you have set "wrap_content" your textview does not have any fixed bounds.